# How to solve the prob using peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg command with argument '--signature-policy'

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I am using Hyperledger Fabric v2.3.1.I am trying to approve my chaincode definition with argument
--signature-policy "OR('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')" instead of the default endorsement for the test-network. The whole command is below

```
peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg  -o orderer.example.com:7050 \
  --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA --channelID mychannel --name fabcar \
  --version 1.0 \
  --package-id fabcar_1:762e0fe3dbeee0f7b08fb6200adeb4a3a20f649a00f168c0b3c2257e53b6e506 \
  --sequence 1 --signature-policy "OR ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"
```

And I get this result

```
2021-06-09 11:56:14.132 CST [chaincodeCmd] ClientWait -> INFO 001 txid [f77193563630eaca758a4e3e360e77625be3bba51a7ac361e0353291a9441ffc] committed with status (VALID) at localhost:7051
```

However, when I commit the chaincode definition(the whole command is below), I got this error message

```
peer lifecycle chaincode commit  -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA --channelID mychannel --name fabcar --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles $PEER_CA --version 1.0 --sequence 1
```

```
Error: proposal failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'CommitChaincodeDefinition': chaincode definition not agreed to by this org (Org1MSP)
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Please add your errors as text instead of images. This will make your answer easier to understand and it will allow it to be indexed by the search engines, so in the future someone can google the error and get to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add flag `--signature-policy`when you commit your chaincode,like these

```sh
peer lifecycle chaincode commit  -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA --channelID mychannel --name fabcar --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles $PEER_CA --version 1.0 --sequence 1 --signature-policy "OR ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually,my pros has been solved by LI Xian.However, I found something confusing.When I used the command below to alter the default endorsement policy with argument '--signature-policy'.

```
peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg  -o orderer.example.com:7050 \
  --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA --channelID mychannel --name fabcar \
  --version 1.0 \
  --package-id fabcar_1:762e0fe3dbeee0f7b08fb6200adeb4a3a20f649a00f168c0b3c2257e53b6e506 \
  --sequence 1 --signature-policy "OR ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"
```

Then I entered 'peer lifecycle chaincode checkcommitreadiness' sub-command, and I got this confusing result.

```
{
    "approvals": {
        "Org1MSP": false,
        "Org2MSP": false
    }
}
```

The result showed I didn't get any approvals from either orgs, but I still could commit my chaincode definition.Maybe it is a bug of Fabric v2.3.1.

Comment: add flag `--signature-policy` when you execute `checkcommitreadiness`,for instance, `peer lifecycle chaincode checkcommitreadiness -o orderer.example.com:7050 --channelID channel1 --tls --cafile ${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/ca.crt --name sacc --version 1.0 --sequence 1 --signature-policy "OR ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"`

Comment: these are  complete steps for you deploy smart contract to a channel,you can find which command you should add flag `--signature-policy`,and which commad you need not.https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fH283vJdkR/